# Batch Script to Recursively Attach String to Filename If Not Present

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Given a folder containing subfolders and text files, my goal is to dive all subdirectories and add  `00` to the beginning of any `.txt` filename that doesn't already contain it. Here's an example:

```
a\1.txt   ----> a\001.txt
a\b\2.txt ----> a\b\002.txt
c\300.txt ----> c\300.txt
004.txt   ----> 004.txt
56007.txt ----> 56007.txt
```

It's okay if `00` is deeper in the filename. By scavenging various threads on this site, I've frankensteined a batch script which works:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s "*.txt"') DO (
     (ECHO "%%a" | FIND /I "00" 1>NUL) || (
          REN "%%~fa" "00%%~nxa"
     )
)
```

Here's my question: **Is there a more concise way to do this?** I've seen a couple posts that use `|FIND` after `DIR`, but I'm not familiar enough with the syntax to understand how it works. I feel like this should be doable in a single line.

Comment: Exclude all txt-files starting with double `0` while listing subdirectories (by **findstr regexp**): `FOR /F "delims=/" %%a IN  ('DIR /b /S D:\0\*.TXT^|FINDSTR /VIRC:".*[\\][0][0][^\\]*$"') DO @echo %%a') DO @echo %%a`. (**DIR** writes list to output. **FINDSTR** filters output using regexp)

Comment: What about a file name `10.txt`? should it become `0010.txt` or `010.txt`? Anyway, `dir /S /B /A:-D "?.txt"` only returns files with base names of one character, and `dir /S /B /A:-D "??.txt"` only returns files with base names of one or two characters, so you could make use of that…

Comment: @aschipfl `10.txt` should become `0010.txt`. Likewise, `01.txt` could become `0001.txt`. It's just important that `00` appears in the title. The actual string I'm searching is more complex and unlikely to accidentally occur.